# Applying macro specific range across sheets

Tags: vba, excel

*Description of inn data*

1.Tables and macro
[image]

2.[Data file in excel with macro and sheets](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-_jipWKnxPvWnVpZThjSTFBc00)

- Table 1 in 1.[Tables and macro] shows the main table without the applied macro.
- The macro works like this: One selects the range where the macro is to be applied, and then it changes the NA value with the previous (above) numerical value in the column where the NA value is located.
- By selecting the range B3:D11 and running the macro generates table 3 (i.e.  in the picture shown, the macro is applied to the following range, and then moved to the right)
- By selecting the range B4:D11 and running the macro generates table 2 (i.e.  in the picture shown, the macro is applied to the following range, and then moved to the right)

*What I have tried*

- I have tried running record macro in excel to attempt making it faster, without any luck.

*Issue*

- I have the same data as depicted in Table 1, in the exact same location in 4 sheets (this is shown in [2.Data file in excel with macro and sheets]). I am therefore wondering on how I can run the macro on all sheets, to generate values such as done in table 2, without including the headers .
- I have many more sheets I need to apply this on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than running the code with `Selection`.

Change the procedure name to `Sub FixData(rng As Range)`.
Change `Selection` in the code to `rng`.

Write another procedure to pass the ranges to the procedure:

```
Public Sub Test()
    With ThisWorkbook
        FixData .WorkSheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:D11")
        FixData .WorkSheets("Sheet2").Range("B4:D11")
    End With
End Sub
```

Place all the code in a normal module.

To run the code on all sheets in your workbook use the code below.  To exclude certain sheets include the lines marked with `'**`.

```
Public Sub FixOnAllSheets()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case wrkSht.Name                     '**
            Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2"                 '**
                'Do nothing or do something else.
            Case Else                               '**
                FixData wrkSht.Range("B3:D11")
        End Select                                  '**
    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. The code works when I add the other procedure. I was wondering however, how do I apply it to all the sheets at the same time? I have about 2000 sheets I need to apply it on. Do I have to manually type in 

FixData .WorkSheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:D11")
FixData .WorkSheets("Sheet2").Range("B4:D11")

all the way to sheet2500? 

Or is there an easier way?

Comment: I've added to my answer showing how to run the code on all sheets in your workbook.  Will it be the same range your looking at on each sheet?  That would need some additional code if it isn't.

Comment: Worked perfectly!